# Create function with arguments of another function in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have created one function `Dummyfunc` which calculates fold-change for different samples.
I am using `gsva` function inside this `Dummyfunc` function. I want to access all the arguments of the `gsva` function from my `Dummyfunc` so that I can change the values of the arguments as per the need.
So far I have tried doing like this :-

```
Dummyfunc <- function(method="gsva",verbose=TRUE,kernel=){
gsva(method=method,kernel=kernel,verbose=verbose)
}
```

But can it be done in automated fashion so that all arguments of `gsva` function can be accessed from `Dummyfunc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are after, but would about using `...`. For example:

```
Dummyfunc = function(...)
     gsva(...)
```

or

```
Dummyfunc = function(method="gsva", verbose=TRUE, ...)
     gsva(method=method, verbose=verbose, ...)
```

We use `...` to pass any additional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

if i understand your problem correctly, you should just pass them all with `...`  you could potentially write them all out, but that might take a while.

```
# define the internal function
f.two <- 
    function( y , z ){
        print( y )
        print( z )
    }

# define the external function,
# notice it passes the un-defined contents of ... on to the internal function
f.one <-
    function( x , ... ){
        print( x )

        f.two( ... )

    }

# everything gets executed properly
f.one( x = 1 , y = 2 , z = 3 )
```